# used not to be so bad

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The road was heavy with mud. It was labour to move along it. The old, wide way, forsaken and grown over with grass, used not to be so bad.

I am not sure how to understand the passage in bold. I think that it is connected to the noun "way". Does "used not to be" mean that the road was in the past quite good (the phrase used + to "verb")?

Comment: ***Way*** there is a (slightly poetic) shortening of ***pathway*** (or more accurately in this *exact* context, ***roadway***). And the construction ***used not to be so bad*** (also slightly poetic / literary) is just a different way of expressing what most of us would convey using ***to do*** as a "helper verb" today: ***didn't use/used to be so bad***. (But don't ask whether that should be ***use*** or ***used*** - so far as I'm concerned, the answer to that is ***Nobody knows!*** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "way" just means "path". It is a noun here.

That is the right understanding. Compare the formation of the negative in to different past tense forms.

> It used to be not so bad
>   It used not to be so bad.

The first means that *in the past it was ok, but now it isn't*.

The second means *in the past it wasn't as bad as it is now*.

But those are pretty similar; there is a lot of overlap.

The example sentence means that the road (which is wide but old and unrepaired) is in a bad condition. But in the past it wasn't as bad as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to James K's answer:

There are several possible negations of "X used to be Y".

> X used **not** to be Y.
>
> X used to **not** be Y.
>
> X **did not/didn't** use to be Y.

I agree there is overlap between "used *not* to be" and "used to *not* be", but I think so much so that they pretty much mean the same thing.  Any difference is based more on context than word order.

Since all of these negations sound slightly awkward, which you choose depends on personal preference and perhaps regional differences.  I tend to say "didn't use to be".

> The old, wide way **did not use to be** so bad.

Alternately, you can avoid this awkward negation by instead negating the adjective:

> The old, wide way used to be **better**.